# Can Jersey Client automatically encode POJO entities into application/x-www-form-urlencoded, or do I need to write custom MessageBodyWriter?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am calling a RESTful web service using Jersey's [`Client`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e618) class along with Jackson to handle serialization to/from JSON. I am also using the `JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING` setting to have Jackson automatically serialize my POJOs to JSON.

The remote service I'm sending my POJO to consumes `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` and produces `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE`.

Do I have to create my own `MessageBodyWriter` implementation to handle POJO serialization into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or does Jersey provide an implementation that does this for me using my POJO annotations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jersey does not have a support for converting arbitrary POJO's to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. It can convert instances of [Form](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/representation/Form.html), or MultivaluedMap. So either your method would have to return one of these, or you will have to write your own MessageBodyWritter.

Comment: I am not sure, but my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067927/how-to-serialize-a-pojo-into-query-params-with-jersey) might be related. If that is a solution, can you answer [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067927/how-to-serialize-a-pojo-into-query-params-with-jersey), explaining how I could write my own MessageBodyWriter?